# Why Source.fromInputStream is working with GZIPInputStream but not with ZipInputStream

Tags: scala, inputstream, scala-streams

I am trying to stream a zip file.

The following chunk of code prints line by line as expected:

```
val inputStream = new GZIPInputStream(new FileInputStream("/some/path"))
val source = Source.fromInputStream(inputStream)
for(line <- source.getLines) {
  println(line)
}
```

But this one doesn't do anyting (it doesn't even exit):

```
val inputStream = new ZipInputStream(new FileInputStream("/some/path"))
val source = Source.fromInputStream(inputStream)
for(line <- source.getLines) {
  println(line)
}
```

The only difference is the usage of `GZIPInputStream` instead of `ZipInputStream`. Both class implements `InputStream`.

Am I missing something ? Or is there any workaroud ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Gzip is just a compressed file, that can be de-compressed on the fly as you are reading from `Source`.
Zip isn't really a stream, it's just one of many java misnomers (take a look at the [interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipInputStream.html)), it's more like a directory, containing several files, that you can traverse via `ZipEntry`, and read each one separately via `Source`. There is no real content at the top level, just a directory listing, so no "lines" to fetch via `Source`.

In a nutshell, you just iterate through entries, creating a new Source for each one. Something like this:

```
   Iterator
     .continually(zip.getNextEntry)
     .takeWhile(_ != null)
     .map { e => 
        e.getName -> Source.fromInputStream(zip).getLines.toList
     }
```

(This creates a `Map` of name of each file in zip to its entire content n memory, probably, not what you want at all, just an illustration of what you can do to access that content via `Source`)

Comment: Yeah I just realized that. What I'm trying to do is to unzip and read a really large file from an URL. I don't want to store it. If you know a way to do it you would make my day.

Comment: Well, in a nutshell, you just iterate through entries, creating a new `Source` for each one. Something like this: `Iterator.continually(zip.getNextEntry).takeWhile(_ != null).map { e => e.getName -> Source.fromInputStream(zip).getLines.toList)`